# Get all possible sums from a list of numbers

Tags: dynamic-programming

Let's say I have a list of numbers: 2, 2, 5, 7

Now the result of the algorithm should contain all possible sums.

In this case: 2+2, 2+5, 5+7, 2+2+5, 2+2+5+7, 2+5+7, 5+7

I'd like to achieve this by using Dynamic Programming. I tried using a matrix but so far I have not found a way to get all the possibilities.

Comment: So, you want the output to be an array containing values : 4,7,12,9,... for your case?

Comment: Exactly. An array with the results indeed.

Comment: There's a DP solution to find the sum of all the possible sums from a subsequence of the numbers in the array. that is, the sum of 

{2}

{2},{2,2}

{5},{2,5},{2,5},{2,2,5}

{7},{2,7},{2,7},{2,2,7},{5,7},{2,5,7},{2,5,7},{2,2,5,7}

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on the question, I think that the answer posted by [AT-2016](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6564115/at-2016) is correct, and there is no solution that can exploit the concept of dynamic programming to reduce the complexity.

Here is how you can exploit dynamic programming to solve a similar question that asks to return the sum of all possible subsequence sums.

Consider the array {2, 2, 5, 7}: The different possible subsequences are:

{2},{2},{5},{7},{2,5},{2,5},{5,7},{2,5,7},{2,5,7},{2,2,5,7},{2,2},{2,7},{2,7},{2,2,7},{2,2,5}

So, the question is to find the sum of all these elements from all these subsequences. **Dynamic Programming** comes to the rescue!!

Arrange the subsequences based on the ending element of each subsequence:

1. subsequences ending with the first element: {2}
2. subsequences ending with the second element: {2}, {2,2}
3. subsequences ending with the third element: {5},{2,5},{2,5},{2,2,5}
4. subsequences ending with the fourth element: {7},{5,7},{2,7},{2,7},{2,2,7},{2,5,7},{2,5,7},{2,2,5,7}.

Here is the code snippet:

The array 's[]' calculates the sums for 1,2,3,4 individually, that is, s[2] calculates the sum of all subsequences ending with third element. The array 'dp[]' calculates the overall sum till now.

```
 s[0]=array[0];
 dp[0]=s[0];
 k = 2;
 for(int i = 1; i < n; i ++)
 {
    s[i] = s[i-1] + k*array[i];
    dp[i] = dp[i-1] + s[i];
    k = k * 2;
 }
 return dp[n-1];
```

Answer (score 2):

This is done in C# and in an array to find the possible sums that I used earlier:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    //Set up array of integers
    int[] items = { 2, 2, 5, 7 };

    //Figure out how many bitmasks is needed

    //4 bits have a maximum value of 15, so we need 15 masks.
    //Calculated as: (2 ^ ItemCount) - 1
    int len = items.Length;
    int calcs = (int)Math.Pow(2, len) - 1;

    //Create array of bitmasks. Each item in the array represents a unique combination from our items array
    string[] masks = Enumerable.Range(1, calcs).Select(i => Convert.ToString(i, 2).PadLeft(len, '0')).ToArray();

    //Spit out the corresponding calculation for each bitmask
    foreach (string m in masks)
    {
        //Get the items from array that correspond to the on bits in the mask
        int[] incl = items.Where((c, i) => m[i] == '1').ToArray();

        //Write out the mask, calculation and resulting sum
        Console.WriteLine(
            "[{0}] {1} = {2}",
            m,
            String.Join("+", incl.Select(c => c.ToString()).ToArray()),
            incl.Sum()
        );
    }

    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Possible outputs:

```
[0001] 7 = 7
[0010] 5 = 5
[0011] 5 + 7 = 12
[0100] 2 = 2
```

Comment: For a 4 element array, you need to enumerate 15 strings( 2^4 - 1). So, the complexity of the solution is O(2^n) ??

Comment: @User_Targaryen Yes, there may be sequences of numbers where the total number of distinguishable sums is less than that (the most degenerate case being the sequence [0, 0, 0, 0, 0] with only one sum, but [1, 1, 1, 1, 1] only has 5 different sums if we ignore the "no elements" sum), but in the general case, the set of sums of (up to) N items is 2^N.

Answer (score 0):

This is not an answer to the question because it does not demonstrate the application of dynamic programming. Rather it notes that this problem involves *multisets*, for which facilities are available in Sympy.

```
>>> from sympy.utilities.iterables import multiset_combinations
>>> numbers = [2,2,5,7]
>>> sums = [ ]
>>> for n in range(2,1+len(numbers)):
...     for item in multiset_combinations([2,2,5,7],n):
...         item
...         added = sum(item)
...         if not added in sums:
...             sums.append(added)
...             
[2, 2]
[2, 5]
[2, 7]
[5, 7]
[2, 2, 5]
[2, 2, 7]
[2, 5, 7]
[2, 2, 5, 7]
>>> sums.sort()
>>> sums
[4, 7, 9, 11, 12, 14, 16]
```

Answer (score 0):

I have a solution that can print a list of all possible subset sums.
Its not dynamic programming(DP) but this solution is faster than the DP approach.

```
void solve(){
    ll i, j, n;
    cin>>n;
    vector<int> arr(n);
    const int maxPossibleSum=1000000;
    for(i=0;i<n;i++){
        cin>>arr[i];
    }
    bitset<maxPossibleSum> b;
    b[0]=1;
    for(i=0;i<n;i++){
        b|=b<<arr[i];
    }
    for(i=0;i<maxPossibleSum;i++){
        if(b[i])
            cout<<i<<endl;
    }
}
```

```
Input:
First line has the number of elements N in the array.
The next line contains N space-separated array elements.
4
2 2 5 7

----------
Output:
0
2
4
5
7
9
11
12
14
16
```

The time complexity of this solution is O(N * maxPossibleSum/32)
The space complexity of this solution is O(maxPossibleSum/8)